# How to add refiners to a SharePoint online classic search page

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint online classic search page that I would like to add some more refiners to. The page currently looks like this.

[image: SharePoint online classic search]

How do you add refiners on the search page?

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint Server 2013/2016/2019:**

- [Plan to use refiners on a search results page in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/plan-to-use-refiners-on-a-search-results-page)
- [How to add refiners to your search results page in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page)

**SharePoint Online:**

- [SharePoint Online: How to Add a Custom Refiner to Refinement Panel in Search Results?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/02/sharepoint-online-how-to-add-custom-search-refiner.html)